# Redirect example.com to www.example.com in PlayFramework 1.2.x

Tags: java, redirect, playframework, url-rewriting

I'm using PlayFramework 1.2.x

I want to redirect the my url `example.com` to `www.example.com`

The only thing I could think of was to set this in the `application.conf`

```
 prod.application.baseUrl=http://www.example.com/
```

But this doesn't lead to mydomain.com/some-page being rewritten as www.mydomain.com/some-page

Is this possible within PlayFramework 1.2.x?

P.S. I can make it work for the root url by redirecting to www.example.com, but I need to make this work for all the other pages, and it's not really practical to redirect to a particular URL for the other pages.

EDIT: edited the question to

Comment: i think `example.com=www.example.com`

Comment: why dont you just redirect in controller like `return redirect("url2");` and you should have both domain booked for your application

Comment: @singhakash well I can make it happen for the root url, but it's all the other urls that I need to make it work for. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 1):

You want to redirect url `example.com` to `www.example.com`.

**Approach 1:**

controller

```
  @With(CheckUrl.class)
  public  class Application extends Controller{
        public static Result index() {
                return ok(index.render("Unable to resolve host."));
            }
    }
```

CheckUrl.java

```
public class CheckUrl extends play.mvc.Action.Simple {

    public F.Promise<SimpleResult> call(Http.Context ctx) throws Throwable {

        String host = request().host();
        System.out.println("HOST IS "+host);

              if (host.equalsIgnoreCase("example.com")) {

             return F.Promise.pure(redirect("http://www.example.com"));

        }

}
```

So when everytime user hits the url in browser it will be send from controller to CheckUrl.java and redired to `wwwdot`.It not the cleanest approach so

**Approach 2:** Standard approach

[Source1](http://typesafe.com/activator/template/play-multidomain-seed),[Source2](https://github.com/adrianhurt/play-multidomain-seed/blob/master/app/Global.scala)

Comment: I'll try something similar, but am using 1.2.x rather than 2.x