# Get everything after the root domain name from an HTTP request

Tags: java, http, playframework, http-headers

Is it possible to get everything after the root domain name from an HTTP request using Java?

So if the url being requested is `http://example.com/my-path` then I'd like to get the value of `my-path`

I'm using the PlayFramework so if there's a header called "Path" or something like that it should be easier to get it with:

```
String path = request.headers.get("path");
```

But this page suggests that such a thing doesn't exist:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields

If there's a different solution to get the same result, that would also be appreciated. If it is possible it will provide a solution to this question as well:

```
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28503129/redirect-example-com-to-www-example-com-in-playframework-1-2-x
```

Comment: Ideally just the path after the root domain, but I guess I could strip out the domain as well

Comment: Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 3):

To get *everything* after the domain, use `uri`:

```
String path = request.uri();
```

Or if you want to cut out query string parameters, use `path`:

```
String path = request.path();
```